# How to install and use the Ruby on Rails metal generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, rack

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying start using Rails Metal.

Typing the following in the Terminal

```
rails generate metal authentication
```

I get this:

```
Could not find generator metal.
```

**So, how can I install the `metal` generator (like a plugin, gem or other)? Where I can find that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metal was removed in Rails 3. Here's the commit w/some notes about it:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ed34652d1aca148fea61c5309c1bd5ff3a55abfa

Comment: So, what I have to do in order to use the rack?